# How to disable intelligent indent for text/markdown files?

Tags: filetype, filetype-markdown, indent

Since ever in my configuration of vim text and markdown-files are indented on following lines to align with open parenthesis.

```
Text Text Text (e.g. Hello
                World)
More Text
```

This happens when I create a new-line by line-breaking or when I run `gg=G`.

How do I disable this for these Filetypes?

I tried disabling `autoindent`, `smartindent`, ain't working.

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose set cindent?` And how about `:verbose set indentexpr?`

Comment: For all these years I thought that `cindent` is automagically only applied to C/C++ filetypes, but it is applied to every ft if put in .vimrc as it is my case.

Answer (score 3):

As [discussed in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/how-to-disable-intelligent-indent-for-text-markdown-files#comment36966_21082), this behaviour is caused by `cindent`.

You can check what's setting this with the command:

```
:verbose set cindent?
```